# How to compare specific keys in JSON?

Tags: java, json

I have two JSON files. I need to compare only specific keys in both of them.

How do I remove all the rest of the keys from the JSON file?

An example for JSON 1:

```
{
"score" : "100"
}
```

An example for JSON 2:

```
{
"Tests": [ {"score":"100"} ]
}
```

I wish to get only the "score" key and value and ignore all other keys and values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) is a good fit here. It allows you to search for occurrences of a key wherever it is found in a json document.
Here is an example using the question details:

```
import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // deep-search for "score" key in all the json doc
        String searchAllScores = "$..score";
        try (InputStream is1 = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("c:/temp/xx1.json"));
                 InputStream is2 = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("c:/temp/xx2.json"))) {
            List<String> keys1 = JsonPath.parse(is1).read(searchAllScores);
            List<String> keys2 = JsonPath.parse(is2).read(searchAllScores);
            System.out.println(keys1);
            System.out.println(keys2);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

if I put the two jso docs in the two files mentioned in the code sample, I get output:

```
    ["100"]
    ["100"]
```

Comment: Toda Raba! Azarta li me'od

Comment: Your code is good, but the score key can be anywhere. How to modify your code in order to check for the key inside of arrays etc'

Comment: check the documentation of JsonPath. you have wide arrays of search criteria patterns

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the structure in the json string then you can use this function to extract the string value and compare them`

```
public static String getStringValueForKey(String json, String key) {
        int keyPos = json.indexOf(key);
        int caretPos = json.indexOf(":", keyPos);
        int valueQuoteStart = json.indexOf("\"", caretPos);
        int valueQuoteEnd = json.indexOf("\"", valueQuoteStart + 1);
        return json.substring(valueQuoteStart + 1, valueQuoteEnd);
    }
```

`

Comment: Your code takes only the first occurrence of the key. How should I modify your code in order to get all occurrences of the keys?

Comment: in that case, i would go with  Sharon Ben Asher's answer - using JsonPath